# How to close active jQuery tools tab?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using jQuery Tools tabs, and I want to be able to close any active tab when I click on it, so  that all tabs become inactive.

How can I, after opening a tab, close it back again?  I can't find any solution to this.

This is my head code:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", {
          /* tabs configuration goes here */

          initialIndex: 'null',
          });
    });
</script>
```

and this is my body:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- tab "panes" -->
<div class="panes">
    <div>pane 1 content</div>
    <div>pane 2 content</div>
    <div>pane 3 content</div>
</div>
```

This is the code in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r527afoa/).

Comment: Paste your code here so we can help.

Comment: Please recreate your problem in JSFiddle.

Comment: my bet is you would have to destroy the tabs and reinitialize, or customize the plugin

Comment: I really need a solution for this. Can anyone help?